# WHERE Clause Requires Like When Equals Should Work

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a query that I think should look like this:

```
select *
from Requesters
where CITIZEN_STATUS = 'OS-IE ';
```

The field CITIZEN_STATUS, whose data type is varchar(15), has a trailing space for this particular value. I have pasted it into Notepad++ and looked at it with a hex editor, and the final space is indeed 0x20.

For the query to work, I have to write it like this:

```
select *
from Requesters
where CITIZEN_STATUS like 'OS-IE%';
```

So, obviously, I have a workaround and the question is not urgent. But I would really like to know why the first query fails to do what I expect. Does anyone have any ideas?

I should mention I am using SQL Server 2005 and can provide more information about the configuration if needed.

Comment: Do you want to know how to preserve the trailing space for the comparison? Or how to suppress it? It isn't clear. And what datatype is CITIZEN_STATUS?

Comment: It's more of a theoretical question. I want to know why I cannot use the equals sign and put exactly what is in the field, rather than having to use LIKE with a wildcard character. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 5, this query works. However, it does not distinguish on trailing whitespace. The query matches 'OS-IE ' as well as 'OS-IE'. In SQL Server 2005 you can use a regular expression that defines the end of a line. The correct character for this is the dollar sign '$' to indicate that you do want the space. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx